# Cypress - get element without assertion

Tags: cypress

How do I get an element in Cypress without it asserting that it is present?

`cy.get('.something')`

Sometimes my element might not be there and I don't want it to fail the test.

Is there a different command I should be using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cypress: Can I prevent Cypress cy.get from failing if no elements are found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150776/cypress-can-i-prevent-cypress-cy-get-from-failing-if-no-elements-are-found)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `cy.$$('selector')` to *synchronously* query for an element (jquery).

If you want this to happen after a cypress command, you'll need a `.then`:

```js
cy.visit('/')
cy.get('element-one').then(() => {
  const $el2 = cy.$$('element-two')
  if ($el2.length) {
    // do this
  } else {
    // do that
  }
})
```

Comment: What if $el2 is inside a shadow root/ shadow dom? How do we find the element in that case? I have posted a related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77131280/cypress-how-to-iterate-over-elements-and-filter-out-ones-which-have-a-shadow-d

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this section of the docs in Cypress
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Element-existence